# Connect to nginx (VirtualBox, Fedora) from Windows host

Tags: nginx, virtualbox

Fedora in VirtualBox running django dev server (bound to 0.0.0.0:8000) and nginx (listening to  port 90)

I have NAT connection set up for the VM and port forwarding 8000 -> 8000, 8001 -> 90

I can see django as 127.0.0.1:8000
But no response from 127.0.0.1:8001

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Dumb question: Can the Fedora guest connect OK to nginx running locally?

Not so dumb question: Have you used tcpdump/wireshark/smartsniff or a similar tool to see if the traffic is making it through the host->guest at all? perhaps the Fedora firewall is blocking non-local connections to port 90?

Also, why not just add a "Host Only" second network adapter to the Fedora guest and forget about fiddling with the NAT settings?

Comment: Can the Fedora guest connect OK to nginx running locally? — yes.

add a "Host Only" second network adapter to the Fedora guest and forget about fiddling with the NAT settings

hm, may be an option